# Generate a 3d List

Tags: prolog

I am trying to make a List of Lists of Lists without values. If N_meses = 4 I want List =[[[A,B,C,D]]].
I get what I want ( List = [[[]]] ) but every lists have the same values as you can see in the print I attached. How can I change this code so every lists have a different "value"?

I am doing this

```
generate_table(Num_investigadores, Num_actividades, N_Meses, Tabela) :-
    length(Row, Num_actividades),
    length(X,N_Meses),
    maplist(=(X), Row),         
    length(Tabela, Num_investigadores),
    maplist(=(Row), Tabela).
```

[image]

Comment: This is due to the `=(X)` part of `maplist/2` is there a specific reason why you do that?

Comment: Yes, I want the list that is repeated always with the size equal to N_Meses. If N_Meses = 4 Something like this [[[A,B,C,D],[E,F,G,H]],[[I,J,K,L],[M,N,O,P]]....]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is in essence the:

```
    %% ...
    maplist(=(X), Row),
    %% ...
```

Here you basically defined a list `X`, and then you set with `maplist/2` that *all* elements in `Row` are unified with that `X`. In the unification process. This thus means that all the elements of `Row` will in essence point to the *same* list.

Nevertheless, I think it would definitely help if you make the predicate *less ambitious*: implement helper predicates and let each predicate do a small number of things.

We can for example first design a predicate `lengthlist/2` that is the "swapped" version of `length/2`, and thus has as first parameter the length and as second parameter the list, like:

```
lengthlist(N, L) :-
    length(L, N).
```

Now we can construct a predicate that generates a 2d rectangular list, for example:

```
matrix(M, N, R) :-
    lengthlist(M, R),
    maplist(lengthlist(N), R).
```

here we thus first use `lengthlist` to construct a list with `N` elements, and then we use `maplist/2` to call `lengthlist(N, ...)` on every element, such that every element is unified with a list of `N` elements. We thus construct a 2d list with `M` elements where every elements is a list of `N` elements.

Then finally we can construct a 3d tensor:

```
tensor3(L, M, N, T) :-
    lengthlist(L, T),
    maplist(matrix(M, N), T).
```

Here we thus construct an *L×M×N* tensor.

We can in fact generalize the above to construct a arbitrary deep cascade of lists that is "rectangular" (in the sense that for each dimension, the lists have the same number of elements), but I leave this as an exercise.

Comment: With L=5,M=4 and N=12. I get this [[[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[]]]

The 12 variables are missing inside...

Comment: @Cyzl: after swapping `listlength` with `lengthlist` (that was I typo), I get: `T = [[[_2732, _2738, _2744, _2750, _2756, _2762, _2768|...], [_2804, _2810, _2816, _2822, _2828, _2834|...], [_2876, _2882, _2888, _2894, _2900|...], [_2948, _2954, _2960, _2966|...]], [[_3054, _3060, _3066, _3072, _3078, _3084|...], [_3126, _3132, _3138, _3144, _3150|...], [_3198, _3204, _3210, _3216|...], [_3270, _3276, _3282|...]], [[_3376, _3382, _3388, _3394, _3400|...], [_3448, _3454, _3460, _3466|...], ...]].`

Comment: I had already swapped listlength with length list. It was an error in other thing. Now it works. Thanks a lot!